# Android default spinner arrow resource

Tags: android, resources, spinner, default

I created a custom spinner. But I cant find the default spinner arrow resource.
In the line

`<bitmap android:gravity="bottom|right" android:src="@drawable/RESOURCE" />`

the drawable is needed.

**spinner.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="@color/white" android:type="linear" />

                    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/primary_light" />

                    <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>

            <item >
                <bitmap android:gravity="bottom|right" android:src="" />
            </item>

        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

**SOLUTION:**
Download from: [Link](https://design.google.com/icons/index.html) "**arrow drop down**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android `Spinner` widget by default uses below image - `btn_dropdown_normal.9.png`

[image]

There are several others for different states like pressed, diabled,etc.

So, the arrow is not a different resource instead it is a part of the complete dropdown image.

Comment: where can I find the single arrow?

Comment: Here try this - https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=arrow_drop_down&style=baseline